# Django 1.7 built in migrations vs South migrations?

Tags: django, django-migrations

I have checked about that issue in questions and couldn't found any simple explanation about Django build in migrations or - Are they reliable enough ?

I started new project with Django 1.7 and facing a lot of problems with the build in migrations. Simple things that was normal in South raise me exception in that version. For example changing charfield to foreignkey raise error that cannot cast the field type to int, something that is normal and that's why i am making the migration. 
As I know what things I had to make with South in my previous projects I strongly doubt that django migrations will handle such operations ? For example custom fields introspections, converting foreign key to manytomany,abstract classes change to fields,  and many others ...
So my question is:

> Are Django 1.7 build in migrations are reliable enough for big
>   complicated normalized database structure ?

P.S. At least as powerfull as south(If the problem is in my use of them I will handle it, but I don't want to fall in a situation where my project is ready, database has a lot of records and I have to change something that requires table deletions and other risky operations).

Answer (score 4):

You have to know that Django Core migrations has been written by Andrew Godwin, who is the main contributor of South.

And his words were:

> *"South's four-year-old design hitting serious limits, it's time to add migration support into Django itself"*

So, understand that Django Core Migration is not a "parralel" migration system, but a new one, and supposed to be a better one. I don't know south very well, but if you're facing errors with core migrations, it could be because it does not work exactly the same way than South, and some things need to be achieve in a different way. I don't think it's because this new tool is not reliable.

Of course, as a new tool, you have to be careful with bugs (go update to 1.7.1) but Django is an extensively tested and very stable framework.